# I'm trying to get an object to move in a predetermined square in JS

Tags: javascript

I am creating a basic airplane game, and attempting to get the enemy planes to move in a rectangular formation. I am able to get them to move down to the correct space on the screen, but when I add the code to move left, up or down the screen goes blank except for my background. I used 5 differenct functions here, one for each direction, looping to the next function in line at the end. Any help to get this moving correctly would be amazing!

```
function moveEnemies(){
    moveEnemiesDown();   
}
function moveEnemiesDown(){
    for(var idx = 0 ; idx < enemies.length; idx++)
        if(enemies[idx].top <= 360){  //down
            enemies[idx].top = enemies[idx].top + 2
    };
    moveEnemiesleft();
}
function moveEnemiesleft(){
    for( var idx = 0 ; ide < enemies.length; idx ++)
        if(enemies[idx].left > 20){ //left
            enemies[idx].left = enemies[idx].left - 2
        };
        moveEnemiesUp();
    }
function moveEnemiesUp(){
    for( var idx = 0 ; ide < enemies.length; idx ++)
        if(enemies[idx].top > 10){ //up
            enemies[idx].top = enemies[idx].top - 2
        };
        moveEnemiesRight();
    }
function moveEnemiesRight(){
    for( var idx = 0 ; ide < enemies.length; idx ++)
        if(enemies[idx].left < 800 ){ //right
            enemies[idx].left = enemies[idx].left + 2
        };
        moveEnemiesDown();
    }
```

Comment: When it goes "blank" it's probably because the game looped stop because of an error. Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: Should ide not be idx instead (in your moveEnemiesleft, ..up, and ..right functions)? What's in enemies?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is you calling all the methods in an endless loop. Check this out:

```
function moveEnemies(){
    moveEnemiesDown(); // you begin calling here, its fine
}

function moveEnemiesDown(){
    for(var idx = 0 ; idx < enemies.length; idx++) {
        if(enemies[idx].top <= 360){  //down "safety hatch", its okay
            enemies[idx].top = enemies[idx].top + 2
        }
    };
    moveEnemiesleft(); // invoke next step
}

function moveEnemiesleft(){
    for( var idx = 0 ; ide < enemies.length; idx ++) {
        if(enemies[idx].left > 20) { //left, ok
            enemies[idx].left = enemies[idx].left - 2
        };
        moveEnemiesUp(); // get to the next moves
    }
}

function moveEnemiesUp(){
    for( var idx = 0 ; ide < enemies.length; idx ++) {
        if(enemies[idx].top > 10){ //up, ok
            enemies[idx].top = enemies[idx].top - 2 
        };
        moveEnemiesRight(); // move right
    }
}

function moveEnemiesRight(){
    for( var idx = 0 ; ide < enemies.length; idx ++) {
        if(enemies[idx].left < 800 ){ //right, ok
            enemies[idx].left = enemies[idx].left + 2
        };
        moveEnemiesDown(); // move down, but then your airplanes don't move
        // since they are already enemies[idx].top > 360 at some point,
        // and all the functions keep looping without moving your airplanes
    }
}
```

Aside from that, you probably have missed a bunch of `{` and `}` here and there. To fix your problem, add this statement to `moveEnemiesDown`:

```
function moveEnemiesDown(){
    if (enemies[0].top > 360) return; // this will end the function sooner, and won't make your code stuck
    for(var idx = 0 ; idx < enemies.length; idx++) {
        if(enemies[idx].top <= 360){  //down
            enemies[idx].top = enemies[idx].top + 2
        }
    };
    moveEnemiesleft(); // invoke next step
}
```